# Winning criterion for a combinatorial game

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, combinatorial-game-theory

Given $n$,
let $\mathcal{R}$ be a set of pairs $(\rho,A)$
where $A\subseteq n, \rho\in 2^A$.
Consider the following game between A and B.

At each round $t$, A enumerates an $m\in n$ (that has not been enumerated
before) and B
presents a $i_m\in 2$. Let
$A[t]$ denote the set of $m$'s A
has enumerated by round $t$ and  $\rho[t]\in 2^{A[t]}$
denote the string $m\mapsto i_m$.
A wins at round $t$ if $(\rho[t],A[t])\in \mathcal{R}$.

Question: Is there some general criterion on $\mathcal{R}$ ensuring A wins (with $|A|<n$
where $A$ is the set of $m$ A enumerated during the game)?
For example: for every $\rho\in 2^n$, there are "many"
$A\subseteq n$ such that $(\rho\upharpoonright A, A)\in \mathcal{R}$.

Comment: What do you mean by A wins? You only defined "wins at round $t$".
Are there multiple rounds? When does the game end?